# scorm 1.2 + declaring objectives

Tags: scorm

I have been looking all over the internet for resources but I cannot seem to find any that describe what I am looking for. I am trying to find out how to create learning objectives ("cmi.objectives.n.id") in scorm 1.2. I dont know whether they need to be declared in the imsmanifest file like they do in scorm 2004 or whether they are created at run time. Either way desperately need to know how to create them. I have found lots of resources on how to do this for scorm 2004 but I cannot find any for scorm 1.2.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

*if I am not mistaken* in SCORM 1.2 you don't declare objectives in the imsmanifest.xml file, you can only LMSSetValue() them at runtime. Keep in mind that the LMS is not required to store them permanently, but only during the SCORM session (between LMSInitialize() and LMSFinish()).
The same holds for interaction in SCORM 1.2